# Data in linked list being overwritten

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linkedlist named info that stores two const char* variable. 
Here is the insert node function:

```
void add_user(Node **head,const char *id, const char *password) {
     Node *n = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
     n->id = id;
     n->password = password;
     n->next = *head;
     *head = n;
     printf("%p--\n", &n); //This address happens to be same all the time
}
```

And here is the loop that calls the function:

```
while (until eof) {
    add_user(&info->head,(const char*)id-i, (const char*)password-j);
    printf("==%s\n", info->head->id);//I tried this and this prints out properly
}
printf("%s\n", info->head->next->id); //this prints out the concatenated value of this node and the previous one
```

Yet, if I try printing out this way:

```
 Node *cur = info->head;
     while (cur != NULL) {
             puts(cur->id);
             cur = cur->next;
     }
```

the output seems as if the nodes are being overwritten every loop:

```
apple
bananaapple
cherrybananaapple
```

As I wrote in the comments, the address of the head never changes, and I am not sure if it's supposed to be same. Also, when I try to print out the element in the loop, it prints out fine.

Comment: Printing `&n` tells you the address of the local variable, not the value of the pointer stored in it, which is the interesting value.  Drop the `&`.  And since you aren't making a copy of the string, the value is indeed being overwritten.  You always need to make sure you know where your data is stored so that you know it is being preserved correctly.

Comment: What is `until` ????

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, it changes after every loop after dropping the '&'.

Comment: @wildplasser That's just pseudocode. I'm reading from a file and storing that into a linked list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How would I have to modify the code to preserve correctly?

Comment: SYNTAX ERROR. (I dont't read pseudocode. I've seen too much of it)

Comment: @wildplasser Sorry I thought that part wouldn't be that much of a problem, so didn't bother.

Comment: Maybe `n->id = strdup(id); n->password = strdup(password);` — and remember to free those before freeing the node that holds them.  The `(const char *)` casts in the calling code should be unnecessary (the ones in `add_user(&info->head,(const char*)id-i, (const char*)password-j);` — you should be able to use: `add_user(&info->head, id-i, password-j);` unless you've done something really weird with `id`, `i`, `password` and `j`.

Comment: Please present the actual code of minimum to reproduce the problem.